# Subtract two polygons in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon, subtraction

I'm drawing three polygons on Google map that the first one is in the second and the second is in the third.
I want to get the subtract of them in javascript as another shape .

P3-P2 ?
P2-P1 ?

Comment: Maybe you can post a crude picture of what you're looking for? I'm not sure what shape you're ultimately trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

Easier that what I thought:

```
var poly1Area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poly1.getPath());
var poly2Area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poly2.getPath());
var poly3Area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poly3.getPath());

poly2Area = poly2Area - poly1Area;
poly3Area = poly3Area - poly2Area;
```

ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#spherical

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I probably had the same problem and the attribute `paths` (plural) helped me.

```js
const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [path1, path2, path3],
    // ...
});
```

Documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-hole